# Create a trigger on all the last_modified columns in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, trigger, row-modification-time

In PostgreSQL 9.5, I have tables with columns in the form

```
prefix_last_modified timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT  (clock_timestamp() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')
```

I was looking for a way to set the last modified value automatically updated at each update of the rows, and I found [this nice post](http://www.revsys.com/blog/2006/aug/04/automatically-updating-a-timestamp-column-in-postgresql/) that defined the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_modified_column() 
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    NEW.modified = now();
    RETURN NEW; 
END;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

Now, I'd like to know if there is any way to pass the column name to the PostgreSQL function and to execute it to the `NEW` row? E.g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_modified_column(varchar column)   
    RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
    BEGIN
        NEW.column = now();
        RETURN NEW; 
    END;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

Comment: I've updated my answer with a new one that use SPI.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## `spi` module: [`moddatetime`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/contrib-spi.html)

**moddatetime — Functions for Tracking Last Modification Time**

> `moddatetime()` is a trigger that stores the current time into a `timestamp` field. This can be useful for tracking the last modification time of a particular row within a table.
>
> To use, create a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger using this function. Specify a single trigger argument: the name of the column to be modified. The column must be of type timestamp or timestamp with time zone.
>
> There is an example in [moddatetime.example](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/contrib/spi/moddatetime.example).

### Example / Synopsis

From the above [referenced file](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/contrib/spi/moddatetime.example),

```
DROP TABLE mdt;

CREATE TABLE mdt (
    id      int4,
    idesc       text,
    moddate timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);

CREATE TRIGGER mdt_moddatetime
    BEFORE UPDATE ON mdt
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE moddatetime (moddate);

INSERT INTO mdt VALUES (1, 'first');
INSERT INTO mdt VALUES (2, 'second');
INSERT INTO mdt VALUES (3, 'third');

SELECT * FROM mdt;

UPDATE mdt SET id = 4
    WHERE id = 1;
UPDATE mdt SET id = 5
    WHERE id = 2;
UPDATE mdt SET id = 6
    WHERE id = 3;

SELECT * FROM mdt;
```

### Your Application

So this is what you would need to.

```
CREATE EXTENSION moddatetime;

CREATE TRIGGER mdt_table
  BEFORE UPDATE ON table
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE moddatetime (prefix_last_modified);
```

Comment: Instead of `CREATE EXTENSION spi;`, `CREATE EXTENSION moddatetime;` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Technically it is possible. For example:

```
--drop table if exists t1;
--drop table if exists t2;
--drop function if exists foo();
create table t1(x int, q int);
create table t2(y int, q int);

create function foo() returns trigger language plpgsql as $foo$
begin
  raise info '%', tg_argv[0];
  raise info '%', new; 
  execute $$select (b).* from (select $1 #= hstore($2||'=>666')) as a(b)$$ using new, tg_argv[0] into new;
  raise info '%', new;
  return new;
end $foo$;

create trigger tg_def before insert on t1 for each row execute procedure foo('x');
create trigger tg_def before insert on t2 for each row execute procedure foo('y');

nd@postgres=# insert into t1 values(1,2);
INFO:  x
INFO:  (1,2)
INFO:  (666,2)
INSERT 0 1
nd@postgres=# insert into t2 values(1,3);
INFO:  y
INFO:  (1,3)
INFO:  (666,3)
INSERT 0 1
nd@postgres=# select * from t2;
╔═════╤═══╗
║  y  │ q ║
╠═════╪═══╣
║ 666 │ 3 ║
╚═════╧═══╝
```

You have to install [`hstore` extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html) for this code.

However it could to extremely slowing down the DMLs because of `execute` using.