# Automating timestamp fields in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, row-modification-time

I'm trying to define the following table in PostgreSQL:

```
posts
- uuid
- title
- created_at
- updated_at
- deleted_at
```

The idea is that i never delete anything, so i change the deleted_at instead of removing the row and use `where deleted_at is null` for normal behavior.

Is there a way of automating those timestamps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different columns,

- `created_at` this simple, just give it a `DEFAULT now()`
- `updated_at` use the [`spi`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/contrib-spi.html#idm46428633933920) module which provides a higher-order trigger than can be applied to any table, see [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/157096/2639), also see [row-modification-time](/questions/tagged/row-modification-time)
- `deleted_at` how would you automated that anyway? What would that even look like? Just set it when you delete the post.

Comment: Isn't there something like MySQL's ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP?

Comment: No PostgreSQL tries not to create a complex system of adhoc macros. But the spi method is pretty easy. `CREATE TRIGGER mdt_table
  BEFORE UPDATE ON table
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE moddatetime (prefix_last_modified);` see the link above Just give it the table, and column name.